# How to call an event handler and a state from a parent component to a child component in a recommended way by using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react redux in an application.

I am trying to send an event handler (with a state) from a parent component to a child component
I have developed a separate Alert component for the reusability in different parent components
Please see my tried code

```
-- CustomizedAltert.js ------
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import MuiAlert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

function Alert(props) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} variant="filled" {...props} />;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    '& > * + *': {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  },
}));

export default function CustomizedAltert({props,childCloseHandler}) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }
    setOpen(false);
  }; 

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Snackbar  open={props.open}  anchorOrigin={{ vertical:'middle', horizontal:'right' }}   autoHideDuration={props.duration} onClose={childCloseHandler} >
        <Alert onClose={childCloseHandler} severity={props.type}>
            {props.message}
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>     
    </div>
  );
}

---- ParentComponent.Js----------------------
import CustomizedAlert from './components/CustomizedAlert';
const showAlert = (obj) => {   
  if(obj)
  {        
   if(obj.name)           
   return <CustomizedAlert open={true} type="error" duration={6000} message={obj.message} childCloseHandler={childOnCloseHandler}></CustomizedAlert >
  }        
}

-- For Child Component Hander and state
childOnCloseHandler = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }
    setOpen(false);
  }; 

export default function ParentComponent() {
 return (        
      <div className={classes.paper}>
      <showAlert customer ={customerObj} />
       </div>
);
```

What should I do in my code?

```
Application built with
{
  "react": "16.13.0", 
  "react-dom": "^16.13.0", 
  "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
  "redux": "^4.0.4"
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5"
}
```

The problem I face is getting a recommended way to create a refined child component without using useRef and forwardRef:

I tried to follow articles and looked up example implementations but could not find the recommended way to solve the the issue.

Comment: Considering you've mentioned about Redux, if the data from child component may be consumed not exclusively by parent, you may dispatch that to your store. If you don't know how to do that, I would recommend to take a look official tutorials in that regard.

Comment: I don't know what is the difference with redux or without it but I just need the reusability. I tried to add alert state and handler in parent but in my case , reason is always undefined at the time of debugging.

Comment: Thank you guys, my issue has been solved. I used const {message, severity, open} = props;
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = React.useState(open); <Snackbar  open={isOpen}  anchorOrigin={{ vertical:'middle', horizontal:'right' }}   autoHideDuration={6000} 
      onClose={handleClose} >  and  my component start to work. thank you everyone